# Efeito jQuery de ads scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso de uma biblioteca jQuery que faça o efeito que é apresentado [nesse site](http://guiadesombrio.com.br/site/).

O efeito que eu preciso é o dos 3 banners no superior da página que ficam com um efeito de *scroll* para a esquerda, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode servir para a sua necessidade
http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Essa biblioteca cria um efeito que não faz a exatamente a mesma coisa que o exemplo da pergunta, mas é parecido:

#### HTML:

```
<ul id="scroller">
    <li><img src="imagem1.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
    <li><img src="imagem2.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
    <li><img src="imagem3.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

#### Javascript:

```
// Inclui as bibliotecas
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>
// O CSS que vem na SimplyScroll
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.simplyscroll.css" media="all" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() { //executa quando o DOM estiver pronto 
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Show, era exatamente o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

O nome desse 'efeito' é chamado carousel. Há muito na internet, destaco a implementações:

- **Bootstrap** http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
- **jCarosel** http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
- **ResponsiveCarousel**    http://basilio.github.io/responsiveCarousel/

Comment: Obrigado Cleiton, ajudou!